# Java script )) Questions about random quiz game

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple random quiz game

I wrote some scripts for the game

```js
var Playerfirstname = prompt("Enter your first name");

var Playerlastname = prompt("Enter your last name");
alert(`Hello ${Playerfirstname} ${Playerlastname}!`);

console.log("Player name is :",Playerfirstname +","+ Playerlastname);

 var round1quiz = [
     ['Whats is 2 + 2', '4'],
     ['What is 3 * 3', '9'],
     ['What is 5 * 5', '25']
 ];

 var round2quiz = [
     ['Whats my name', 'Ian'],
     ['Where am i from', 'India'],
     ['My favorite Food', 'Idly']
 ];

  var round3quiz = [
     ['Whats my name', 'Ian'],
     ['Where am i from', 'India'],
     ['My favorite Food', 'Idly']
 ];
 
 score = 0;
 var questions = 0;

function round1()
{

 shuffle(round1quiz)
 var round1 = prompt("If you want to start Quiz game, enter 'yes'");

 if (round1 == 'yes' || round1 == 'y')
 {
   alert("Let's start Quiz game!");
   alert("Round 1");
   questions = round1quiz;

 }
 else
 {
   alert("sorry, try again");
   var round1 = prompt("If you want to start Quiz game, enter 'yes' or 'y' ");
 }


}

round1();



function round2()
{


}



 function randomQuestions() {
     return [rq(), rq(), rq()]
 }

 function rq() {
     var a = getRandomInt(0, 100),
         b = getRandomInt(0, 100),
         operator = "+-*" [getRandomInt(0, 3)],
         answer = operator === "+" ? a + b : operator === "-" ? a - b : operator === "*" ? a * b:0;



     return ["what is " + a + operator + b, answer]
 }

 function getRandomInt(min, max) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
 }

 function askQ(ans) {


     var answer = prompt(ans[0], '');
     if (answer == ans[1]) {
         score++;
         alert('Your are right!, you get money');
     } else {
         alert('Sorry, It is wrong answer');
         
     }
 }



 // the loop that will ask all the questionseasy

 function startquiz() {
     for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
         askQ(questions[i]);

     }
 }

 startquiz();
 alert(score);

 function shuffle(array) { // 
     var currentIndex = array.length,
         temporaryValue, randomIndex;

     while (0 !== currentIndex) {

         
         randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
         currentIndex -= 1;

         
         temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
         array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
         array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
     }

     return array;
 }
```

I wanna put round2 and round3 in my code

If the player entered all correct answer and choose to play round2, round2questions will display.

However, if the player chooses to stop playing the game, the game will be over
How can I put that code in my script?

Answer (score 1):

First things first: If your intentions are to learn the basic syntax of JS (or the basics of any programming language), keep going.

Your code got some mistakes and wrong concepts. For any other reason (become a webdeveloper/node.js etc.) stop right now, and get into those basics first. ("Understand HTML, CSS and how JS interacts with those" or "How to setup a node server on your maschine and your first "hello world" Programm")

To answer your question: your question is hard to answer, it's a mess. But basically you need to ask user at the beginning of each round, if he wants to continue.

Save each round into an array...

```
var rounds = [round1, round2, round3];
```

... afterwards call each round ...

```
var currentRound;
while (currentRound = rounds.pop()) {
    currentRound();
}
```

What happens: We save the function it self into a variable and call them afterwards.

There are way more improvements, but you could start with this.

Comment: Thank you, I will write new scripts